# PHP - Search box doesnt work

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a search box with classes, i always use a specific code for this, whithout using classes.

But now, im learning how to use classes, and i need to transfer my old code, to a single class, i tried this function:

```
function verGaleria() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cds`";
    if(($rs=$this->bd->executarSQL($sql))){
      if(isset($_GET['buscar'])){
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cds` where name like '%".$_GET['buscar']."%'");
      }

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {                   
              $imagem = $row['imagem'];
              $ID = $row['ID'];
              $artista = $row['artista'];
              $preco = $row['preco'];
              $titulo = $row['titulo'];

        echo '      
                <style>
                .teste{
                text-align:center; display: inline-block; width:300px; margin: 0 0 40px 30px;   float:left; color:white;
                }
                </style>
          <div class="teste">
                  <h1>'.$titulo.'</h1>
                      <h2><img class="cd" src="CDs/'.$imagem.'" width="102" height="126" alt="'.$artista.'"/></h2>
                        <h3>'.$preco.'€</h3>
          </div>
            ';
    }   
  } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

My from code:

```
<form method="GET" name="buscar" >
 <label><a class="utilizador">Procurar</a>
 <br />
   <input type="text" name="buscar" id="prc" placeholder="Ex: Rock"/></label>
    <input type="submit" class="submitprc" value="Pesquisar" />
</form>
```

Comment: what is the issue? Did you deliberately leave the `action` attribute from the form tag?

Comment: @LuckySoni, It doesn't work :)

Comment: @Atle What doesn't work? What happens when u do what? lol

Comment: it shows all the products on my database

Comment: [Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Also where is your class?

Comment: Is the function `verGaleria()` getting called? Is the `$rs=$this->bd->executarSQL($sql)` succeeding?

Comment: Why does your form have the same name as the input?

Comment: Replace $rs with $sql in while loop

Comment: @Mihal, better to replace `$sql = mysql_query` with `$rs = mysql_query` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the initial SQL query `$sql = "SELECT * FROM`cds`";` which fetches all the products and storing all results in `$rs` like so `$rs=$this->bd->executarSQL($sql)`

Then you check if search query is present `isset($_GET['buscar'])` and if it is present then you form your new sql statement `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`cds`where name like '%".$_GET['buscar']."%'");` but you never execute it.

Then you use `$rs` to show the results..

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $imagem = $row['imagem'];
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $artista = $row['artista'];
    $preco = $row['preco'];
    $titulo = $row['titulo'];
//code
}
```

What you should do is something like:

```
<?php

isset($_GET['buscar']) ?
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cds` where name like '%".$_GET['buscar']."%'" :
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cds`";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cds` where name like '%".$_GET['buscar']."%'", $conn); // pass in your connection object

 if(! $result )
 {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $imagem = $row['imagem'];
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $artista = $row['artista'];
    $preco = $row['preco'];
    $titulo = $row['titulo'];

   //code
}
```